# Automatically expand height of DIV according to the div displayed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a div sliding thing, as you can see in this [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/mq2c2129/14/)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#moving").click(function(){
      $("#moving").toggleClass("left");
       $("#right").toggleClass("right");
   });
});
```

Here is the complexity that I am using:

I have 12 Right Side DIVS, they are all set display: none, except one. 
On the moving DIV I have a list of links to other hidden DIVs. They are shown or hidden with show or hide jQuery function....

It all works with height set to 700px (so I can accomodate a lot of content)

How can I make the height automatic according to the content? If, let's say Div number 5 has more content and scroll is required... how can I expand it and show it?

I hope you guys can help me. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery something like this will use the largest of the children's heights for all the children `div`'s of `#wrapper`.

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
        var maxHeight = 0;
        jQuery("#wrapper > div").each(function () {
            var thisHeight = jQuery(this).height();
            maxHeight = thisHeight > maxHeight ? thisHeight : maxHeight;
        }).height(maxHeight);

});
```

Added a sample here:
https://jsfiddle.net/mq2c2129/15/

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will check it out now.

Comment: and css height? I put min-height initially in style.css but nothing is happening..

Comment: Added a jsfiddle - you whilst "window load" works for me, inside jsfiddle it wasn't working so moved to inside "document ready". You might want to use "window load" if you have images or other external content to ensure the height of those elements is included. I'll leave you to test on a super slow connection and see what works for you.

Comment: Thank you:) Very kind of you